# How do I implement maxfilter (with a given radius) in ruby-vips?

Tags: ruby, image-processing, filtering, vips

I want to do a thing like this:

[image]

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxFilter.html

Lets say my image has one channel (is grayscale).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it with PI * R * R convolutions.

```
R = 2
D = R + R + 1
CIRCLE = Vips::Image.black(D, D).draw_circle(1, R, R, R, fill: true).to_a

new_image = image
D.times do |i|
  D.times do |j|
    next unless CIRCLE[i][j] == [1]
    t = image.conv Vips::Image.new_from_array Array.new(D){ [0]*D }.tap{ |t| t[i][j] = 1 }
    new_image = (new_image > t).ifthenelse(new_image, t)
  end
end

return new_image
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a square window, you can do this with a rank filter:

```
result = image.rank w, h, w * h - 1
```

http://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/API/current/libvips-morphology.html#vips-rank

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-vips/Vips/Image#rank-instance_method

Where `w` and `h` are the width and height of the window.

Of course, max/min are separable, so you could also write this as:

```
result = image.rank(w, 1, w - 1).rank(1, h, h - 1)
```

which would be much faster for a large radius.

Comment: Window shape is of course important. Though this is interesting method. Maybe it's possible to express a circle of radius 5 as two overlapping rectangles of 3x5 and 5x3 ans somehow combine results. Not sure about larger radiuses but this can be faster than my method.

Comment: That's a clever idea. How large an R do you need to work for?